# After Upgrade to dotnet core 3.1 sdk, localhost not serving pages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a handful of dotnet core projects on my mac development environment with VS Code. After installing the dotnet core 3.1 sdk, I cant connect to any of my sites on localhost. Ive tried about 6 different asp.net core projects, all on different ports and I cant connect.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what was your previous version of **dotnet core sdk**?

Comment: Previous version was 3.0

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but you are using non-standard ports, are you navigating to correct addresses? Screen shot indicates that app is starting.

Comment: Are you trying to visit the website via `http://localhost:5201` (`http` instead of `https`), or `https://localhost:5200` (`https` instead of `http`)?